# Subversion conflict in filename case

Tags: svn

I'm using a Subversion repository where someone copied a filename to the same filename using a different case (at least, I'm pretty sure this is what happened). Something like:

```
svn copy FILENAME.xml filename.xml
```

This person *neglected*, however, to delete `FILENAME.xml` from the repository (I work in a team of mainly non-developers so it's unlikely they realized this). Now there is a situation in which both filenames (uppercase and lowercase) exist in the repository.

This wouldn't be so much of a problem except that I am using a Mac on a case-insensitive filesystem: when I update my working copy, the lowercase version overwrites the uppercase version I get the warnings that my working copy is incomplete, and I can't get the exclamation marks to go away. I don't really use this particular repository except to check up on a couple of things occasionally, and I'm not terribly familiar with Subversion.

What I want to do is to delete the all-caps name entirely in favor of the lowercase name. I can't do this because when I try to `svn delete` the file it deletes the lowercase version.

Comment: You forgot to make a question. Do you want to ignore one of the files (or both) when you check out? Do you want to remove one of the files (or both) from the repository?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Oops! Just added one, thanks.

Comment: you will want to add a hook to prevent case clash in the future. check out http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/case-insensitive.py

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way would be to remove the file directly on the repository. The [svn delete subcommand](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.delete.html) accepts two kind of arguments, either a PATH (working copy) or a URL (repository)—simply use the second one:

```
svn delete -m 'Fix broken rename' http://example.com/svn/foo/bar/FILENAME.xml
```

Comment: This seems to work (a clean checkout had no problems), so I accepted it. I'm now getting the "Can't open file: No such file or directory" error when I try to update to the latest version in my working copy...it seems like the `.svn` directory is messed up somehow? Any thoughts?

Comment: The Subversion working copy format is not as robust as it should. I've learnt to ignore these kind of working copy issues and simply make a fresh checkout. It's just not worth the effort.

Comment: Fair enough. I just removed the offending directory completely and did an `svn update` to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should better rename the file, for example file to file2. 
Do commit.
After rename file2 to File and the conflict will be solved.